# Sorting array that contains strings in both french and english

Tags: php, sorting, multilingual

The problem I am having is that when I call sort() on my array of strings, it alphabetizes it fine, except for french strings.

It will sort it like so:

```
Atlantic Inc.
Bait Inc.
Zack's Fish Mart
Émile Fisheries Inc.
```

What can I do to sort both languages appropriately?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Collator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php) class yet? That might be what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sorting rules are highly dependent on the locale.
You can force a locale using the SORT_LOCALE_STRING flag:

```
setlocale("LC_ALL", "fr_FR.utf8"); 
sort($arraytobesorted, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: I used your solution, but it is putting Émile in between two A's

Comment: Could you please post a short example with a static array, so I can check it? Thanks.

Comment: Figured it out. I just needed to add "fr_FR.utf8" onto the file. Works perfectly. Could you edit your answer to reflect that change? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is being sorted correctly. 'É' comes after 'Z' in your default locale.

To change this behaviour, set the second parameter of `sort()` to 'SORT_LOCALE_STRING' and change your system's locale to one that supporting the ordering you desire.

Comment: I did that, but it puts é at the beginning of the array.